# Download image from HTML creates black areas in the image

Tags: c#, image, webclient

I have a C# program that downloads images. One of the images I try to download is this one:
http://chipii.dk/1323-large_default/armb%C3%A5nd-med-hjerte-sort.jpg

I download it using this code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(csvFields[CSVField.Photourl], temporaryFilename);
}
```

But for some reason my downloaded file ends up having black areas:
http://www.smykker.me/produkter/1377-armbaand-med-hjerte-sort.jpg

Anyone has any idea why this happens - and what I can do about it?

Thanks,
Mads

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Save the image as .png instead of .jpeg and everything works fine.

Comment: But why? The 'why' part of your question is the one people will be interested in in the future (and I'm curious now).